# Add metering area or focus area in android via Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, parameters, camera

i made a camera application to capture an image on android and i access the camera via intent. I want to know if i can add a focus area or a metering area to this application with intent and not building a camera app from start in order to put some extra parameters. My phone is Samsung Galaxy S GT-I9000.